# Bootstrap Circle Modal

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a bootstrap modal in a circular Form. Already created one but my problem is how can i insert the Text in the middle of the circle modal responsively?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #0099FF;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 100%;
  }
</style>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Flex box` will help you, and I have removed `padding-top` that was pushing content in bottom. for height I have used `height:100vw` and `max-height:600px` that will make box proper circle shape.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<style>
  .modal-content {
    background-color: #0099FF;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    max-height: 600px;
  }
</style>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad! I could help.

Comment: Can i ask one more thing about the flexbox? why isn't my firefox supporting the syntax? Already added the
"
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
"

Comment: Check whether your version of firefox supports Flex Layout http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: As it says that its compatible with my firefox 51.0 (Ubuntu). But the html displays the texts more over to the right and not centered. But in my Chrome it works well.

Comment: I have no Idea about `Ubuntu` but for me in Firefox (windows), it works quite well.

Comment: You really Helped me a lot sir. Ill try it on a windows machine to see if it works and other devices. When i fix it here in ubuntu i will inform you right away Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Append a div to `model-content` and give it `position:absolute` and position it to be in the center

```
<style>
   .modal-content {
      background-color: #0099FF;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding-top: 100%;
   }
   #text {
     position: absolute;
     top:50%;
     left:45%;
   }
</style>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
   Modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div id="text">Lorem ipsum</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example : http://www.bootply.com/kBT3elyYFV